# Triggering an Asynchronous process in Java

Tags: java, mysql, asynchronous, triggers, daemon

I have a web application that takes in user requests and puts them into a MYSQL database. Now a typical user request needs to be serviced by following a workflow that would take significant time to complete. To address this i have an asynchronous processor that keeps listening to the MYSQL table.

I have noticed that polling the MYSQL table on an infinite loop results in a spike in CPU usage on the box my application is deployed to that often renders the box unusable.

I know that making the asynchronous process sleep for 'some' time whenever there aren't any  active requests in the MYSQL database is an option but i would like to keep that as a last resort.

Making this process synchronous is not an option because of the time the workflow involved in servicing a single request takes and also because there is a need to decouple the processing from the front end to allow the back end to evolve.

I would like to know if there is any smart way to trigger off the asynchronous process so that i can avoid the CPU usage spike and still get optimum response time from the asynchronous processor.

Any advices would be appreciated.

Thanks
p1ng

Comment: The way that you've framed this question suggests that you have two separate applications. Is there a reason that you can't have a multi-threaded web application that asynchronously processes the data that was just inserted in the database?

Comment: For all practical purposes, the frontend and backend can be considered as different applications. The reason i can not go the multi-threaded way is because the workflow involved in processing each request utilises resources that are singular and non threaded and i did not want to block on those resources on a per request basis. Also the asynchronous processor is still evolving and the need for decoupling is also because we have plans to open this up for external API calls in future.

Comment: Can you detail why you are getting a CPU usage spike?  Apart from making the back end multi-threaded as well, I don't see what you can do without understand why you have a problem in the first place.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Polling the database for requests is the entry point of the asynchronous process. I have deployed the asynchronous process as is and without the 'infinite loop poll' before assuming that the infinite polling is causing a CPU spike. Also FYI, a 'top' command run on the box shows a java process to be consuming ~90% cpu. This asynchronous process is the only java app deployed on the box.

Comment: Do you have more detail about what exact it is doing? e.g. using a CPU/memory profiler or using performance testing of individual components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to store the request in the database AND send some kind of event in you system (eg. JMS message, or by using java.util.concurrent constructs). The process that reads and executes the command can then be awaken by this signal, go fetch the data in the database and process it as usual.

This way, you wouldn't waste CPU cycles polling not-yet-available data, and you would be more reactive due to the absence of polling delay.

Comment: Thanks, JMS is the path i intent to take.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your asynchronous process read from a TCP socket or something similar. The asynchronous process should just wait blocking on i/o. Then from your primary process you can send a message over to the asynchronous process once it has updated the table. It may be possible to send the message from a trigger in database too.

Comment: This is interesting. How would you send messages from a trigger? Do you have an example or a link?

Comment: @perissf Following link suggests it may be doable http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-10

Answer (score 1):

I would generally not recommend polling based approach to check the table. What happens when you have to poll for different events at different schedules? If you envision need for multiple events in the future, I would suggest looking into message queues for asynchronous tasks.

But if you have to go with polling based approach for now - I don't fully understand your reasoning against letting the asynchronous process sleep for some time? Why would you want your process to consume all the CPU resources doing nothing but running in an infinite loop? Why not have your async process run at specific intervals? You can make this polling interval configurable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) Java API to do that. See [that blog entry](http://technology.amis.nl/blog/4859/asynchronous-processing-in-java-applications-leveraging-those-multi-cores).

Or perhaps just `new Thread(YourRunnable).start()`, and make some state variable in `YourRunnable` to know if your task is finished or not.